# How can I use python entry_points for data files?

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I have a small python library that extends a python workflow management system by supplying a set of reusable rules (like Makefile targets) as files in a small minilanguage.

This is working great using `pkg_resources` in a directory in my package.  I can discover these resources easily using `pkg_resources.resource_filename` and friends.

I would like to allow other users to be able to provide their own rule files in python package form.  It seems that folks use `setuptools` `entry_points` to allow this type of functionality, at least when extending code with plugins and the like.  Is there a way to apply the entry_point idea to package resources and not just python code or other suggestions about how to allow someone else's package to register data that my package can find?